# Limit Document Insertion for Embedded Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, document

I am curious find out if I can create/enforce some limitations on a mongoDB document. I want to limit MongoDB embedded documents to a certain amount of records (10). I am creating a password check system that will query Mongo and check to see if the user's password is either a) like their current password, or b) matches one of their 10 oldest passwords. If there is no match, then the DB will be updated with the newest password and the old passwords document would be updated with the last current password. However, I want to limit this to 10 records, and over-write the oldest record so there are only ever 10 passwords in the oldPassword document.

Does this make sense? And is it possible to enforce such a limit? The mock object would look like the following:

```
_id: "",
username: "User",
currentPassword: "pass"
oldPasswords:{
    password1: "pass1",
    password2: "pass2",
    password3: "pass3",
    password4: "pass4",
    password5: "pass5",
    password6: "pass6",
    password7: "pass7",
    password8: "pass8",
    password9: "pass9",
    }
```

As a sidebar: Is this is the best way to handle the passwords in Mongo? I have read their [modeling documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/data-modeling/) and it appears that a 1 to many relationship like this would be best in an embedded document, unless the embedded document continues to grow. Then, at that point, it seems that referencing the old passwords would be best served in its own document.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can switch old passwords to an array instead of an object, you can use [slice](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/tutorial/limit-number-of-elements-in-updated-array/).

```
db.passwords.update(
   { _id: 1 },
   {
     $push: {
        oldpasswords: {
           $each: ["passabc"],
           $slice: -10
        }
     }
   }
)
```

That should keep the last 10 passwords on your array.

Comment: Is this only limited to arrays? Would there be any way of keeping the format I mentioned above, as an object with key value pair? I suppose I could do the same with array as well.

Comment: I believe it's limited to arrays.